# If user logged in and user id or level ="x" then show some

Tags: codeigniter

I want to check if user logged in and SESION ID = "5" or level ="1" then show list. how to do it?

```
      <?php if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) : ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>posts/create">Sukurti skelbimą</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>categories/create">Sukurti kategoriją</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>users/logout">Atsijungti</a></li>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine expressions by using logic operators and braces to make sure the correct things are compared.

Your example could then be something like this:

```
if( $this->session->userdata('logged_in') && ( ($sessionID == 5) || ($user_level == 1) ) )
```

Have a look at [Logical Operators](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/language.operators.logical.php) to learn more about this.